# Why $\left<X, X\right>=1$? ( where $X$ has a mean of zero and a variance of $1$)

Tags: inner-products, correlation

I was looking at the proof of [Two Random Variables, Each Correlated to a Third](https://web.archive.org/web/20171026064532/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62860.html).

I can't understand some parts of the proof regarding inner product. For example, in the proof, it mentions that let's assume that $X$, a random variable, has a mean of $0$ and a variance of $1$, so does $Y$. Why is that $\left<X, X\right>=1$ and that $\left<X, Y\right>$ is the correlation
coefficient of $X$ and $Y$? For $\left<X, X\right>$, I think that $\mathrm{Var}(X) = 1 = E(X^2) - 0 = \left<X, X\right>/n$ but not $\left<X, X\right>$.

Comment: The dot product defined on random variables is : $ < X,Y > = \mathbb{E}[XY]$. Hence, if your random variable has unit variance and 0 mean, you get 1.

Comment: @yjnt : Is <X, Y> = E[XY] for random variables a definition? Or is there any intuition behind this?